# purrr with linear model in R: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data frame of species with different abundances and I want to see if their abundances are related to some parameter.

I think I ought to be able to do something like

```
# Load in the dune data set and tidyverse
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
library(tidyverse)

# Reshape the species matrix into long form data
duneM <- dune %>% rownames_to_column('Site') %>% gather(Species, Count, -Site)

# Join the species and environmental data
duneE <- dune.env %>% rownames_to_column('Site')
duneJ <- left_join(duneM, duneE, by = 'Site')

# Basic linear model, that compares species counts to moisture data
my_lm <- function(df){
    lm(Count ~ Moisture, data = df)
}

# Group the data by species and apply the function to each one
duneJ %>% group_by('Species') %>% map(my_lm)
```

To my surprise, I am getting the following error message.

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): invalid 'envir' argument of type
>   'character' Traceback:
>
> 1. duneJ %>% group_by("Species") %>% map(my_lm)
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. withVisible(function_list[k])
> 8. function_list[k]
> 9. map(., my_lm)
> 10. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
> 11. lm(Count ~ Moisture, data = df)   # at line 2 of file
> 12. eval(mf, parent.frame())
> 13. eval(mf, parent.frame())
> 14. stats::model.frame(formula = Count ~ Moisture, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
> 15. model.frame.default(formula = Count ~ Moisture, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
> 16. eval(predvars, data, env)

Clearly, I am missing something here. Could somebody please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: It's expecting a data frame.   Try  `duneJ %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(lm = list(my_lm(.)))`

Comment: Thanks. While that does indeed run, I'm not sure what to do with the output. I had been planning to do something like, `duneJ %>% group_by('Species') %>% map(my_lm) %>% broom::tidy` to get a data frame of coefficients and p values.

Comment: I thought much of the point of map was that it was able to handle objects that are not data frames, and then we could extract the data-frame at some last step with something like map_df(broom::tidy)

Comment: `group_by` works with `tbl` objects such as data frames. See `?group_by`.

Comment: Clearly, I am missing something here. In my understanding, `duneJ` is a data frame, which is passed on to `group by`, which groups the data frame by species. I expected that `map` would then take the smaller, by species data frames, created by `group_by` and then run some function on them, which has some arbitrary output. Then (I had thought) one could convert that output to some data frame, with say `map_df` type format and export it and append the many results together.

Comment: The function doesn't seem to be failing at the group_by stage. Indeed, If I do something like `dune_J %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(a1m = mean(A1))` it at least returns a sensible output, if not the one I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. `group_by` returns a tbl object, but map expects a list as an input. That's why the documentation for map suggests using split. So this works: `duneJ %>% split(.$Species) %>% map(~lm(as.numeric(Moisture) ~ Count, data = .)) %>% map_df(tidy)`

Comment: With one key problem, which is that the species data are no-where to be seen on that data frame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped me to look at this post http://omaymas.github.io/Climate_Change_ExpAnalysis/, and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg to understand how to best use purrr and broom together. As G. Grothendeik points out, I can add a column with models to a data frame (where each cell is a full model). The way to do this with the map function is

```
 duneJ %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest %>% mutate(Mod = map(data, my_lm0)) -> test
```

Here, `nest` is a key function that makes a column that is a list of data frames, each of which contain the data about each species and saves it to a default column named "data". I run `map` inside of the mutate funciton to save the models to yet another column, where each cell is a new model.

If I want to look at model results, I can combine them into a list of data frames with map and broom, select the relevant data, and then `unnest` them, like so:

```
 test %>% mutate(Glance = map(Mod, glance)) %>% select(Species, Glance) %>% unnest
```

This gets me a new data frame that has model results for each species, which was what I was ultimately aiming for, even if I didn't fully explain that in the question.